# How do you conditionally join a string from Table B to Table A, using an aggregate function on Table B date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to do a conditional join from Tickets to Sales. Tickets:Sales is 1:M. My goal is to provide a list of tickets, and the Sales Channel of the first transaction:

Ex:

```
select r.ticket_id, s.channel, min(s.transaction_date)
from reservations r
join sales s on r.ticket_id = s.ticket_id
where r.order_id = '0151841621'
group by select r.ticket_id, s.channel;
```

If I have Reservation ID 123 and it has two records in the Sales table, an online sale and a retail refund, I get the following result

```
r.ticket_id, s.channel, transaction_date
123, Ecommerce, 2019-07-01:00:00:00
123, Retail, 2019-07-02:00:00:00
```

I'm looking for a way to combine this into a single table with 1 reservation record, based on the min(transaction_date).

i.e.
123, Ecommerce

Pusedo code

select r.ticket_id, [s.channel where min(transaction_date)]

i.e. select the Channel with the first transaction date.

I've been searching for "conditional select / conditional join" without much luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (r.ticket_id) r.ticket_id, s.channel, s.transaction_date
from reservations r join
     sales s
     on r.ticket_id = s.ticket_id
where r.order_id = '0151841621'
order by r.ticket_id, s.transaction_date;
```